# Shape does not show

Tags: android, android-layout

The shape     background="@drawable/profile_rounded_top_shape"  is not drawing, what am I missing??

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            background="@drawable/profile_rounded_top_shape"
            android:clickable="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

==> profile_rounded_top_shape.xml <==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/profile_rounded_top_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/profile_rounded_top" /> <!-- default -->
    </selector>
```

==> profile_rounded_top.xml <==

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FF000000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

==> profile_rounded_top_pressed.xml <==

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FF000000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#6633cc"
        android:endColor="#00ccff"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Comment: The namespace? `background` -> `android:background`

Comment: Genius. submit answer for points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background="@drawable/profile_rounded_top_shape"
```

should have the `android` namespace in front of it:

```
android:background="@drawable/profile_rounded_top_shape"
```