# How to make shape's child TextView white when state_pressed="true"

Tags: android, android-layout

This shape is the backround of a linearLayout, how can I make any TextViews within the LinearLayout change their text color to white during the statePressed =true of the parent selector?  Also see my previous question to see more of the code: [Shape does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673373/shape-does-not-show)

```
 <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#AA000000" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#6633cc"
                android:endColor="#00ccff"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressed state is propagated to all child views of a layout. You can declare a state list of colors similarly to how you declare a state list of drawables. If you set a state list color on text within a parent that becomes pressed, the pressed state will apply to the text color as well.

EDIT: The quoted information is partially incorrect and was edited in by someone else:

> USE: android:duplicateParentState="true"  for the TextView, also
>   USE: android:color="@color/myNewColor"

This XML color file is placed in the res/color directory of a project.

Here's an example from AOSP, used for default text: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/color/primary_text_dark.xml

EDIT: You edited my answer with incorrect information. Pressed state is propagated regardless of the `android:duplicateParentState` setting.

View.java, the `setPressed` method invokes `dispatchSetPressed`:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#8521

ViewGroup.java, the overridden `dispatchSetPressed` method sets all child views pressed:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3833

Comment: Thanks for duplicateParentState attribute, it is very important.

Comment: pressed state seems not to be propagated anymore starting with Android 4.1

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextView
android:textColor="#ffffff"
/>
```

Comment: thanks, i realize i was lacking vital information to the question.