# how to change the textView color from selector

Tags: android, background, textview, selector, android-linearlayout

I have LinearLayout  with textView.

I have set the LinearLayout background from selector

```
android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
```

so when pressing the layout it change the background color

my problem is how to change the text color also when pressing the layout

I need something like onStateChangeListner, so when user press the layout it also change the text color

thanks,

Tomer

Comment: You want to use the selector for your textView also na?

Comment: yes, i want to be able to change the text color when state was changed in the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with this code -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void clickme(View view)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);             
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:onClick="clickme"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this with your Selector.

Comment: i try this, still the function never be called

Comment: What? Isn't called? Just debug that?

Comment: I manage to slove it by creating selector for the textColor also

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate of [How to make shape's child TextView white when state_pressed="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673469/how-to-make-shapes-child-textview-white-when-state-pressed-true) which is pretty much the correct answer. duplicateParentState="true" transfers the parent ListView selection state to the TextView child. The following worked for me:

```
<TextView
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and the text_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/text_on" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/text_on" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/text_off" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

put this in onClick of Layout

textview.setTextColor(color);

Comment: it's not helping me because i have a selector for all the sates i want to, i just need to change in additional the textView color

Answer (score 1):

You can set color to textview in two ways
 using xml tag "android:textcolor="colorvalue"
or
 set color by the method "textview object.setTextColor(colorname)" in java code.

Answer (score 0):

in that there is one solution
First create the two images in different color background with text color
second is set the selector as you to apply in above like

`android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"`

its definatly works